# What is Z3's default solver?

Tags: z3, smt

[Novice]. According to http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/strategies, 'smt' is the main tactic on Z3. However, using it explicitly breaks even for trivial problems. How can one reference the default Z3 solver in a tactic sequence?

http://rise4fun.com/Z3/K8nn

```
(declare-fun var1 () Real)
(assert (= (* var1 var1) 9.0))
(assert (< var1 0.0))
; Works
;(check-sat)
;(get-model)
; Breaks
(check-sat-using smt)
(get-info :reason-unknown)
```

Comment: Relevant to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34789949/1959808

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Z3 will look into your formula to determine which features and logics are required and it will then call a suitable solver/tactic. You can provide a (set-logic ...) command to steer it, or you can directly use one of those default tactics. For a list of SMT logics for which Z3 has custom tactics, see [default_tactic.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/tactic/portfolio/default_tactic.cpp). If none of them matches and no logic is selected, "smt" is the tactic that will be executed.

To see which tactics are run, add `-v:10` to the command line, and Z3 will print the tactics names and statistics as they are being executed.

For this type of non-linear reals the "smt" tactic is not very strong and it will give up quickly and return "unknown". But, it isn't the default tactic for this type of problem; instead (after some preprocessing) it is the "nlsat" tactic that solves the problem, as called via the default tactic for QF_NRA (see [qfnra.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/tactic/smtlogics/qfnra_tactic.cpp)).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm running Z3 via the Java APIs. Is there a way to ask Z3 ```ctx.mkTactic(select-best)```, which will invoke the magic selection algorithm for solver after the problem is fully specified? There is a bit of a chicken and egg problem here, as the solver must be built before the problem constraints are added to it. Would it be reasonable to create a comprehensive parOr cocktail of solvers ahead of time?

Comment: Side question: How do I specify ```-v:10``` from the Java API? ```ctx.mkParams()``` doesn't seem to be the right way.  [Thanks for an awesome tool, by the way!]

Comment: Yes, all of this is possible. The constructors for the solver class take parameters, which can be either strings for logic-declarations or tactics. The default mkSolver() is the one that will select a tactic for you, and it will do so after all assertions have been added.

Comment: -v:10 via the API is done by setting the option "verbose" to 10 when constructing the context, e.g., setParameter("verbose", "10") should do it.