# Can we extract the current tactics used by z3, then configure another instance similarly?

Tags: z3

I'd like to reuse the tactics used/activated when setting a particular logic, but I need to avoid using`set-logic`.

So is there any way I can get Z3 to show the tactics/config it is employing, in a reusable form ?

e.g. `(get-tactics)` would answer with something I can use as argument to `apply` or `check-sat-using`

Otherwise what are the possible approaches to deduce the tactics that are deployed as side effect of my set-logic instruction ?

### Some context

I cannot use `(set-logic QF_LIA)`as this prevents me from using `special-functions` such as partial order. But, once I remove the `set-logic`, my UNSAT queries that used to be *fast* (200 ms) become "unknown", for examples that don't use anything other than QF_LIA.

So I understand that setting the logic helps configure the solver, but I now need to bypass this builtin configuration mechanism since I can't use set-logic.

#### What I tried

I've tried some `check-sat-using` but not setting a logic, with mixed results :

- `smt` is pretty fast 400ms
- `qflia` surprisingly is not the same as setting logic, it is slow 20s but finds an answer
- `default` as expected gives unknown, I think (hope) it is the same as basic `check-sat`

None of these are as good as setting QF_LIA (200 ms).

When running Z3 in verbose mode `-v:10` I can see it using `nnf-cnf` in the faster runs, which then helps trigger some simplifications apparently, the slow versions start to branch instead (the result is UNSAT on this example). But this information is hard to exploit, I know Z3 has the right settings for my problems built into it, but how can I trigger them ?

Answer (score 1):

Logic selection and tactics are only loosely related: Selecting a logic dictates which names are in scope. Tactics decide how to actually solve the problem. In general, the two are otherwise unrelated.

But I do see your point that it'd be nice if z3 listed which tactics it applied. I'm afraid what you can glean from the verbose output will be all you have at least for the time being, as there is no `(get-tactics)` or a similar command. You could ask for it in their issue tracker of course, and maybe they can point out some other call you can use. (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues)

Comment: Apparently Z3 strategy applied *is* quite sensitive to the set-logic, see e.g. this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789949/setting-logic-for-solver-in-z3-api/34790861#34790861 . Thanks for the answer, I'll keep looking and then maybe put up a feature request against Z3 if I can't work around it.